# How to properly set JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS?

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-melodic, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am adding a custom sensor arrangement to a `Clearpath Jackal`. In the documentation, it suggests that all is necessary is to set `JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS` to the file path of the custom xacro file. I do this using:

```
echo "export JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS=/home/administrator/my_folder/urdf/sensors.urdf.xacro" >> /etc/environment
```

However, this has no effect. This is shown in the TF tree, which reflects none of the expected changes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I've looked at the instructions here: http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/melodic/jackal/startup.html where it is suggesting that I should use the command:

```
echo "export JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS=/home/administrator/my_folder/urdf/sensors.urdf.xacro" >> /etc/ros/setup.bash
```

However, this still does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371168/how-to-properly-set-jackal_urdf_extras?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2021-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) on 2021-02-11**:
Did you re-source your terminal after adding the new paths?

For the git discrepancy, are you sure you're in the same branch?

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-02-16**:
Please ignore my previous comment regarding the git discrepancy - this was a mistake. I've just tried resourcing my terminal and this does not solve the problem. Is there something else that should be sourced to make sure the Jackal system can see my file in the same way that it can see the preset empty.urdf.xacro file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well you can do in two ways:

1. [`JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS`](https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/melodic-devel/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro#L261) with this you have to do the same procedure as you did above. I think you also have to publish the static transform as well from Jackal to your Lidar.
2. Adding [accessories](https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/melodic-devel/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro#L258) to the robot. This thing is fairly simple and worked quite well for me and also rendered everything in Gazebo and handling was quite easy.

Here is a small example:

```
<!-- front laser -->    
    <xacro:include filename="$(find warthog_description)/urdf/accessories/lasers/front_laser.urdf.xacro" /> 
    <joint name="fl_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0.025 0.0275 0.025" rpy="1.5708 -0.7854 0" />
      <parent link="fl_frame"/>
      <child link="f_laser" />
    </joint>
  </xacro:if>
```

and the `front_laser.urdf.xacro` look something like this"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro"  name="f_laser" >
  <xacro:include filename="hukoyu.urdf.xacro" />
  <xacro:hokuyo_ust-10lx_mount prefix="front" topic="front_laser/scan" location="0.07"/>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [Tahir M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23517/tahir-m./) with karma: 213 on 2021-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1